# Threaded binary search tree where every node must keep a reference to its successor

Tags: performance, binary-search-tree

Given the constraint that every node in the search tree must maintain a reference to its inorder successor, can we maintain the references without ruining the run-time performance of inserting new nodes into the tree. Ideally a way that works by only changing pointers around.